# How can I Generate the random number two times in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram

In the below code, I generate random numbers and then taking the probability and create the graph. now how can I make the graph two times like I want to generate the random numbers again and create graph again.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Random Number Generating
x = np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=100000)


counts = Counter(x)
total = sum(counts.values())
d1 = {k:v/total for k,v in counts.items()}
grad = d1.keys()
prob = d1.values()
print(str(grad))
print(str(prob))
#bins = 20
plt.hist(prob,bins=20, normed=1, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5)
#plt.plot(bins, hist, 'r--')
plt.xlabel('Probability')
plt.ylabel('Number Of Students')
plt.title('Histogram of Students Grade')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Put everything into a function. Call that function twice. (Do you want to get the same random numbers, or different ones?)

Comment: If you want to reproduce the exact  graph -- set an explicit seed to the random number generator. See this: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest i never use function in python. can you put this code in function ? and doesn't matter of  same number or its generate random.

Comment: @JohnColeman how can i call this `numpy.random.seed(seed=None)` in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the function as much as you need!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter

def my_funct():
   np.random.seed(1223) # fixing the seed! but I don't think you need it

   #Random Number Generating
   x = np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=100000)
   counts = Counter(x)
   total = sum(counts.values())
   d1 = {k:v/total for k,v in counts.items()}
   grad = d1.keys()
   prob = d1.values()
   print(str(grad))
   print(str(prob))
   #bins = 20
   plt.hist(prob,bins=20, normed=1, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5)
   #plt.plot(bins, hist, 'r--')
   plt.xlabel('Probability')
   plt.ylabel('Number Of Students')
   plt.title('Histogram of Students Grade')
   plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15)

   plt.show()
#calling the function twice
my_funct()
my_funct()
```